# Python - White plot when asking an input

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, input

I've been trying to make a script that loops over  pandas dataframe columns, for each column it should plot it and ask the user if he/she wants to append the name of that column or not.

I've reduced it to the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# create dataframe
d = {'col1': np.arange(0,10,1), 'col2':  np.arange(0,20,2)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

QC = []
# loop to plot each column    
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    # plot
    plt.figure()
    df[col].plot()
    # ask for an input
    Q = input('Append?: ')
    # do something
    if Q == 'Y':
        QC.append(col)
```

The problem is that it shows white screens and asks for the input; the figures appear as expected only when the loop is over.

What it should do is: show a plot, ask for the input, close that plot and then continue with the next one, and so on. 
I've tried with `plt.show(block = True)`, but I can't make it work it out. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you could add `plt.show()` followed by a timer and `plt.close()`.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it, but I still have the same problem. 
The plot appears after I give the input; and I need to see the plot to give the input.